# Cannot read property of object

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have an Article component and a state with all my articles. I map state to props with the right article I want to display.

`console.log(props.article)` works but `console.log(props.article.title)` or any other attribute does not (I get `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`). why ?

My `Article.js` component:

import React from 'react';

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


const Article = props => (
<div className="aboutpage-wrapper">
  <div className="container">
{  console.log(props.article)}
{/*    <h2>{props.article.title}</h2>
    <h3>{props.articlesubtitle}</h3>
    <p>{props.article.body}</p>*/}
  </div>
</div>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state,props) => ({ article: state.articles.find(function (article) { return article.id === props.match.params.id; })});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Article);
```

Comment: What are you getting for `console.log(props.article)` ?

Comment: It migh tbe the case that at the time of render, the Article might not have `article` inside rhe prop.

Try this: {  console.log(props.article? props.article : 'Article not avaialble yet;)}

Comment: `{id: "3", body: "text here", createdAt: 7890, subtitle: "this is the subtitle.", title: "this is the title"}` @PraveenKumar

Comment: @VikasYadav your code returns `props.article` ! and if I do `console.log(props.article.title? props.article.title : 'Article not avaialble yet')` I also logs the corresponding `props.article.title`. so weird !

Comment: @JulesCorb you can check like `props.article ? props.article.title : 'Article not available yet'.`

Comment: @PraveenKumar this does work indeed, I'll get by with this but I expected to be able to simply use `props.article.title` and so on.

Comment: may be somewhere that `props.article` is getting `null` or `undefined`, so its best to have the condition.

Comment: is there a typo props.articlesubtitle? there seems to be missing a dot.

Comment: I guess props.match.params is undefined. can you show more code to see where this should come from?

Comment: @lipp there was a typo indeed, thanks. `props.match.params` comes from the URL parameters (using react-router-dom) and was defined. I got by with @vikasyadav's solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer drills down the unavailability of props and hence the respective collection inside them.

You should first check for the availability of your prop. You can use the ES6 destructuring operator as:

```
const { article } = this.props;
```

which is same as the

```
const article = this.props.article ? this.props.article : '';
```

Additionally, while rendering out the content inside you can use the same logic for the availability of content inside the `article` as:

```
<h2>{props.article.title ? props.article.title : '' } </h2>
```

#### Alternate Short-circuit logic:

While rendering the content, you can also write like this:

```
<h2>{(props.article || {}).title || ''} </h2>
```

I hope this will help.

Cheers!

Comment: I don't think that last part would be considered short-circuit evaluation; it's a regular ternary operation. Short-circuit is when you do something like `(props.article || {}).title || ''` which would return the title if it's defined, otherwise an empty string.

Comment: Yeah @Chris, Thanks. I totally agree with you. That is just a phrase I was referring to. Please do edit the answer so that we can have this information too.